# ACF and PACF of AR process with non-zero mean

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, partial-correlation

Calculating the acf and pacf of an AR process with zero mean is straightforward, but does anyone knows how to proceed when the mean is not zero? Of course my intention is to calculate the theoretical acf and pacf, and not the numerical values.

Some course books that I have do not help at all, as all of them assume the mean is zero (for simplicity!) and the Internet also has not been any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just subtract the mean from all observations. Then proceed as if the mean is zero.